# Convert string that is all caps to only only having first letter of each word caps

Tags: swift, string

I'm getting strings from a server that is all caps like:

"HELLO WORLD"

but I'm trying to make is so each word is caps on its own like:

"Hello World"

I've tried this:

```
extension String {
    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        let first = String(characters.prefix(1)).capitalized
        let other = String(characters.dropFirst()).lowercased()
        return first + other
    }

    mutating func capitalizeFirstLetter() {
        self = self.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}
```

but the result is

"Hello world"

any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple already did that for you:

```
print("HELLO WORLD".capitalized)
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416784-capitalized